# Trying to get the Facebook SDK for JavaScript to work on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, sdk

i have been trying to get the Facebook SDK for JavaScript working on my wordpress website for a few days now but it keep failing for some reason

i followed the exact steps on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2

i got it to work yesterday (the like button showed up in my header) but when i refresed the website today it was gone and the SDK code stopped working.

i have no idea how it happend since i didn't change anything on the website so i redid the whole thing but without results.

this is how most of my header.php (where the code is suppose to be) looks like

```
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> data-layout="<?php echo esc_attr( stag_site_layout() ); ?>">

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : 'your-app-id',
xfbml : true,
version : 'v2.1'
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<?php
/**
* Aesop Story Engine theme hook.
*
* @since 1.1.0
*
*/
do_action('ase_theme_body_inside_top');
?>

<div
class="fb-like"
data-send="true"
data-width="450"
data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

as you can see the code is directly below the body code. and below that the facebook like code, but it's not working...

if anyone could help me with this than that would be really great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new App ID here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started#create-app

Choose "Website" as the platform.

Once you create a new app, you will see your unique code for "appID". In your code above where it says "your-app-id", place in your new unique code.

Also, your code can be updated to v2.3:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3